# How to timeout at Java thread after the creating thread has already returned?

Tags: java, multithreading, timeout

I'm trying to write a method that creates a thread that does work after this method has already returned. I need this thread to timeout after a certain amount of time.

I have a working solution but I'm not sure if it is the best way to do this.

```
  new Thread(() -> {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Future<Void> future = executor.submit(new Callable() {
            public Void call() throws Exception {
              workThatTakesALongTime();
        });
        try {
            future.get(timeoutMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception from timeout.", e);
        }
    }).start();
```

Is there a better way to do this without using the ExecutorService within the Thread?

Comment: I think your solution is fine. You need something to do the work and something to do the timing. Using just threads, I guess you would spawn a thread, which spawns another thread with your work on it. The outer thread waits some time and then interrupts the inner thread. I think that's essentially what `FutureTask` does, when you call [`get`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.java#l198) with a timeout: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.java#l396

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this.
One way would be, as you did, to use an ExecutorService. A much easier approach is to create a new thread and a queue, from which the thread will look if there's something every few seconds. An example would be this:

```
Queue<Integer> tasks = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

new Thread(){
    public void run() throws Exception {
        while(true){
            Integer task = null;

            if((task = tasks.poll()) != null){
                // do whatever you want
            }

            Thread.sleep(1000L); // we probably do not have to check for a change that often
        }
    }
}.start();


// add tasks
tasks.add(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

See the `ExecutorService.invokeAny()` method that allows you to pass a timeout value.